# Rigify rig not generating. Getting python error whenever I press the button

Tags: python, rigify, error

As the title says, I'm getting an error whenever I try to generate a rig in rigify. I removed the facial bones as I want to use a different method with facial animation and kept everything else that was in the rigging tutorial I was watching. When I finally positioned all the bones as he did in the video, I tried to click generate but all I got was a python error that read:

[image]

Here's what the metarig looks like in case I messed anything up:

[image]

And from the side as well:

[image]

I noticed that there was an extra bone in the foot of the metarig in the tutorial but mine doesn't have that bone to begin with so I just assumed it was because it was a 4 year old video.

Anyway, I appreciate any help I can get and await any respones!